# Is this question not a combination question as opposed to a permutation? why isn't the answer 35?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Question is:

> in a window display at a flower shop, there are 3 spots for 1 plant each. to fill these 3 spots, adam has 7 plants to select from, each of a different type. Selecting from the 7 plants, adam can make how many display arrangements with 1 plant in each spot? (Note: the positions of the unselected plants do not matter.)

If the order does not matter, shouldn't this be a combination? nCr would be 35. the "correct" answer is J (210), but if I understand correctly, that only occurs with a permutation of 7*6*5, which is calculating when order DOES matter. I dont understand why this would be 210 if order clearly does not matter. Any help is appreciated thanks!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG8wf.png]

Comment: The question states, "order of **unselected** plants doesn't matter". But order of the selected plants is to be counted. So, multiply by $6=3!$.

Comment: Oh my goodness! i mis read that in the question. So the order of the ones we do select (3 "spot") DO matter. So this IS a permutations question and you do NOT divide by 3!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom73$ ways to choose $3$ of the plants to be displayed, but there are then $3!$ ways to arrange those $3$ plants in the $3$ display spots. Thus, there are altogether

$$\binom73\cdot3!=35\cdot6=210$$

possible displays.

Choosing the $3$ plants is choosing a combination of plants, but the $3$ spots in the window have distinct identities: their positions are fixed. Thus, if the plants are $A,B$, and $C$, it makes a difference whether we arrange them in the $3$ spots in the order $ABC$, the order $BAC$, or one of the other four orders.

Comment: OH thank you so much I didn't realize that the order DID indeed matter for the selections. So we are not allowed to group together ABC, BAC ... (by dividing by 3!) in this question. thank you!

Comment: @Will: You’re welcome!